# How to load subdomain under a path in the main website (NGINX)?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, react-router

I have wordpress blog running in the subdomain (`blog.example.com`) and website is react app running on `example.com`. I want to load the blog when someone navigates to `example.com/blog`.

(It may not matter, but just additional information is, blog is running inside the AWS Lightsail and directly configured in Route53 and website is running inside the EC2 with nginx serving the page)

**Update:**

I still want the user to see the url as `example.com/blog/abc-def` **not** `blog.example.com/abc-def`. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect example.com/blog to blog.example.com with nginx.

```
location ^~ /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog/?(.*)$ https://blog.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: I still want the user to see the url as `example.com/blog/abc-def` **not** `blog.example.com/abc-def`. Is that possible ?